# How to catch an error when specifying the wrong types of arguments to a generic function in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

Suppose we have the following methods: (I am most interested in the `update()` method)

```dart
class Some {
  void update<T>(T a, T b) {
    // Type `a` and type `b` must necessarily be the same
  }

  T update2<T>(T a, T b) {
    // Type `a` and type `b` must necessarily be the same
    return a;
  }
}
```

The problem is that calling this method with incorrect types in the arguments will not cause a statistical error or hint.

```dart
void main() {
  final some = Some();
  const int valueInt = 5;
  const String valueString = 'str';

  final void a = some.update(5, 'str'); // says it's not a mistake
  some.update(5, 'str'); // says it's not a mistake
  some.update(valueInt, valueString); // says it's not a mistake
  some.update<int>(5, 'str'); // a mistake

  some.update2(5, 'str'); // says it's not a mistake
  some.update2<int>(5, 'str'); // a mistake
  final a2 = some.update2(5, 'str'); //  says it's not a mistake
  final int b2 = some.update2(5, 'str'); // a mistake
  final String c2 = some.update2(5, 'str'); // a mistake
}
```

It turns out that if we forget to specify the type, we will get a very unpleasant error. It is very important to me that the types `a` and `b` are the same, with the `a` parameter type being logically correct at all times. When an error occurs, we always assume that it is type `b` that is specified incorrectly.

What I tried:

1. Seeking to see if there is an annotation that would make a note when using the method without a type
2. Looking for a linter rule mandating the use of `<T>` before calling the `func()` (even if this rule exists, it is not needed anywhere, applications in this function)
3. Perform internal checks in the method for compliance of type `b` with type `a` (This is unnecessary because. will only help to catch the bug in the release by looking at the logs. Probably the worst-case scenario would be to use this)

**So**, I don't want to specify an invalid type `b` that doesn't match type `a`. Otherwise, show a static error/warning. How to achieve this?

Comment: The problem is that any two objects always have the same type. They all share the supertype `Object`

Answer (score -1):

what you have to do is to give your `update` method a type. doing so will ensure that the 2 parameters are of the same type as your update method:

```html
    ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => update<String>('string1, 'string2'),
                  child: const Text('update'))
```

Comment: I understand that, but the thing is, there's no hint so I don't forget to specify this type.